# How do I multiply two String variables?

Tags: java

I want to multiply two String variables and want to store the answer in a new variable. How can I do this?

I have already tried to do the simple:

```
String t2 = t1 * m1;
```

The error was that `*` was undefined. So, I tried adding:

```
import java.math.'whatever';
```

That didn't fix the error.

Comment: What does it even mean to multiply two string variables? What's the product of `"Hello"` and `"World"`?

Comment: I wasn't sure how to present my question. I tried to explain it with the limited knowledge of java and coding in general.

Comment: Maybe explain a little more. Give us some examples of what the calculation is supposed to do (sample values for `t1` and `m1` and what the you would like for `t2`).

Comment: Do you want to multiply two floats or integers and then store their value in a string?

Comment: @Ted Hopp t1 is the first input from user. m1 is the second input which is 2. t2 should be the result of multiplying t1 with m1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
String t2 = String.valueOf(Float.valueOf(t1) * Float.valueOf(m1))
```

Answer (score 4):

use

```
String t2 = String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(t1) * Integer.parseInt(m1))
```

Answer (score 2):

First get the value from `String` and multiply the `parsed value` in following way:

```
double result = Double.parseDouble(t1 ) * Double.parseDouble(m1);
String t2 = Double.toString(result );
```

Have a look on [**Conversion between Numbers and String**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/converting.html)

Answer (score 1):

`*` is undefined because t1 is a String and Strings cant be used in multiplication. If t1 and m1 are stringrepresentations of numbers you can convert them to numbers (chose Integer, Float, Double or whatever is needed in your application) and then multiply. Like this (variable names are none-java-style for extra readability, no bashing about it):

```
    String t1  = "1.5";
    String m1 = "10";

    float t1_as_a_float = Float.parseFloat(t1);
    float m1_as_a_float = Float.parseFloat(m1);

    float t2_as_a_float = t1_as_a_float * m1_as_a_float;

    String t2 = Float.toString(t2_as_a_float);
```

Comment: Better to use Java variable naming conventions

Answer (score 1):

Java doesn't know what it means to convert two arbitrary Strings together (i.e. what's "smelly" * "whale"?). First you need to convert the Strings to numbers, multiply those numbers together, then convert the result back to a String.

```
try {
    double t1_num = Double.valueOf(t1);
    double m1_num = Double.valueOf(m1);
    double t2_num = t1_num * m1_num;
    String t2 = String.valueOf(t2_num);
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    // called if numbers cannot be converted to Strings
}
```

You need the try-catch block to handle the cases when t1 and m1 contain non-digit characters, like "Ryan1" or "fifteen".

Answer (score 0):

> String t1 = "325486";

```
    String m1 = "7868";

    int n1 = Integer.parseInt(t1);

    int n2 = Integer.parseInt(m1);

    int n3 = n1 * n2;

    String t2 = String.format("%d", n3);
```